# Superscript of superscript in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have managed to make a character superscript using the following lines of code:

```
Paragraph p=new Paragraph();     
Span s = new Span();
s.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript;
s.Inlines.Add("2");
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("EXAMPLE 1 : Describe the behaviour of the function f(x)=(x"));
p.Inlines.Add(s);
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("-1)/(x-1) near x=1."));
```

But is it possible to write a superscript of a superscript? Like the one shown below:

```
g(x)=(1+x^2)^(1/x^2)
```

Here the second ^ will be superscript of the superscript. How to achieve this?
Also let me know is it possible to make a program understand that `x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)`, and anything similar to this equation, even the nth degree equations?

Comment: I don't know of any way of typesetting a `<Run>` to a superscript of a superscript.  There are of course use [Unicode superscript characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), which might be enough if all you need to be typeset as a second superscript is numerals.  Regarding your other point, I think the term you are looking for is symbolic computation.  See, for example, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html

Answer (score 4):

You could combine BaselineAlignment.Superscript with Typography.Variant="superscript" like this:

```
<Paragraph FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
    <Run>g(x)=(1+x</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">2</Run>
    <Run>)</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript">(1/x</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" Typography.Variants="Superscript">2</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript">)</Run>
</Paragraph>
```

This will give you an output something like this:
[image: Equation]

Answer (score 1):

This project looks promising:
http://blog.noldorin.com/2010/04/rendering-tex-math-in-wpf/

Your example equation could be written almost un-modified in TeX notation. See: http://www.texrendr.com/?eqn=g(x)%3D(1%2Bx%5E2)%5E%7B(1%2Fx%5E2)%7D