# c# wpf superscript (not in XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, superscript

I have a question to you. How can i make superscript in textblock using only c#?
My aim is to convert string dynamically (the count of '^' signs is dynamically changed) so it's not possible to write it in XAML (or i don't know how to do it).
I tried the code from this link - [Superscript of superscript in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751914/superscript-of-superscript-in-wpf). but it doesn't work :(

Thanks!

Comment: Im thinking that you need richtext block

Comment: So how would it look like?

Comment: I think what you really want is something to render [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536324/markdown-for-c-wpf-project-markdownsharp).

Comment: This is also good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer!
TextBlock can be changed dynamically in this way:

```
Run run1 = new Run("This is ");

Run run2 = new Run("bold");
run2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

Run run3 = new Run(" and ");

Run run4 = new Run("italic");
run4.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;

Run run5 = new Run("text.");

Run run6 = new Run("x");

Run run7 = new Run("2");
run7.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Subscript;

myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run1);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run2);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run3);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run4);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run5);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run6);
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run7);
```